Xero-api Authentication and testing with PHP Pest & PhpStorm
I want to do some testing using Pest on my PHP app.
Through the browser, everything works but as I add more functionality I want to build some complex test scripts - and that means I need to be able to authenticate my "user".
I'm running Pest through PhpStorm but happy to use Terminal instead.
Is there a way to authenticate and run my test scripts?
composer.json:
"require": {
    "xeroapi/xero-php-oauth2": "^7.3",
    "monolog/monolog": "^3.7",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.9.2",
    "tinymce/tinymce": "^7.3",
    "ext-pdo": "*"
  },

